# Python 3 does not recognize special characters

Tags: python-3.x

This is the `app.py` file.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import sys


def run():
    print(sys.argv)
    filename = sys.argv[1]
    print(filename)
    return


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

I want to run this code from the command line, so I tried the two following lines each.

`python3 app.py input.txt`

`python3 app.py < input.txt`

The first command showed the result I expected, which is `['app.py', 'input.txt']`. However the second command just ended up showing `['app.py']`.

It seems like the Python code does not recognize the special symbols. How can I make the script recognize them without changing the script itself? i.e. **not modifying the command like this: `python3 app.py '<' input.txt`.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The < character is special and will actually stream the file specified to stdin. You cannot override this behavior as it comes from your shell not python itself. Here is an example of what is really happening, and how you can get the file contents.

```
import sys

file_contents = sys.stdin.read()  # This will read the entire stdin stream into file_contents
```

This will also work for the | character

```
echo "Hello, World" | python app.py
```

Comment: This is quite helpful for the alternative solution. Thanks!